# Button inside AlertDialog Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have a *AlertDialog.Builder* in my Fragment Page and it shows three *EditText* (in a xml file).
Now I'd like to add a button at the top of the AlertDialog and on its click change the text of two of them.

It is like:

Button : Get coordinates

1st EdiText : latitude

2st EdiText : longitude

Comment: Well you could create an XML layout for your dialog, inflate the view and do something like `popDialog.setView(Viewlayout); `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a button added in xml file to be displayed in AlertDialog, just inflate the layout

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setCancelable(false);
builder.setView(layout);
```

where "layout" is inflated view

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_filename,null); // specify your xml layout here
```

then use "layout" to get id of the button

```
Button btn=(Button)layout.findViewById(R.id.getCoordBtn);
```

add click listener to it and perform whatever you want